# When should I use free() in C?

Tags: c, malloc, free

The code works as it is supposed to, though it never frees the memory allocated by `malloc()`.

I have tried to free memory in any place that I can, but no matter where I do it, it breaks the program. Specifically, I get a "double free or corruption error." This is more of a question as to what `free()` and `malloc()` actually do? All of the problems with free are in the main:

```
int main(int argc,  char *argv[]){
if(argc!=2){
    exit(1);
}

printf("CSA WC version 1.0\n\n");

int length = strlen(argv[argc-1]);
char file_to_open[length];
strcpy(file_to_open, argv[argc-1]);

//printf("filename:%s\n",file_to_open);

//create counters for output
int count_number_of_lines = 0;
int count_number_of_words = 0;
int count_number_of_characters = 0;

//create int size of default array size
int current_array_size = pre_read(file_to_open);
//printf("number of lines: %i\n",current_array_size);

//create string array of default size
char *strings_array[current_array_size];

//create a pointer to catch incoming strings
char *incoming_string=NULL;

int done=0;
while(done==0){
    incoming_string=get_line_from_file(file_to_open, count_number_of_lines);
    if(incoming_string!=NULL){
        incoming_string=csestrcpy2(incoming_string);
        //printf("incoming line: %s\n",incoming_string);
        strings_array[count_number_of_lines]=(char*)malloc(strlen(incoming_string+1));
        strings_array[count_number_of_lines]=csestrcpy2(incoming_string);
        //printf("added to array:%s\n",strings_array[count_number_of_lines]);
        count_number_of_lines++;
        count_number_of_characters=(count_number_of_characters+(strlen(incoming_string)-1));
    }
    else{
        done=1;
    }

}
//all data is stored in a properly sized array


//count all words in array
int count=0;
int word_count=0;
char *readline;

while(count<current_array_size){
    readline = csestrcpy2(strings_array[count]);
    printf("line being checked: %s", readline);

    int i=0;
    int j=1;

    while( j< strlen(readline)+1 ){
        if(strcmp(readline,"\n")!=0){
            if( (readline[i] == ' ') && (readline[j] != ' ') ){
                word_count++;
            }
            if( (readline[i] != ' ') && (readline[j] == '\n') ){
                word_count++;
            }
        }
        i++;
        j++;
    }
    count++;
}
printf("current word count: %i", word_count);
return 0;
}



char* csestrcpy2(char* src){

int i = 0;
char *dest;
char t;
dest = (char*) malloc(MAX_LINE);

while( src[i] != '\0'){

    dest[i] = src[i];
    i++;

}

dest[i] = '\0';
//printf("length:%i\n",i);
free(dest);

return dest;
}
```

Comment: There is no reason to copy `file_to_open` out of `argv`, you can just *use* `argv`.

Comment: Curious about `incoming_string=csestrcpy2(incoming_string);` Is this just a string copy function?

Comment: Also, `malloc(strlen(str+1));` is almost certainly wrong. You probably meant `malloc(strlen(str)+1);`. (And many people, including me, recommend omitting the cast - `void *` pointers will be implicitly converted, and it can cause potential problems if you explicitly convert it to the wrong type.)

Comment: csestrcopy2(incoming_string);

is a string copy method that returns a string that is guaranteed to have a '/0' at the end of the line....

Comment: Please post the entire code from your csestrcopy2 function because, judging by what you posted in the comments, that's part of your problem.

Comment: I recently edited the code to reflect a change that i made on it! the number times malloc() is in the code has been reduced to one... I would like to thank everyone who has been helping me!

Comment: I also added the csestrcpy code as well

Comment: *note csestrcpy is a funtion from another file....

Comment: I do see the catch-22 of trying to free the memory AND returning from the csestrcpy2 function where then you can't access the var outside the scope of the function! Maybe use a global var that can serve as a reusable buffer for that function? Then it can be free'd in any scope as well.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

In general you only have to free memory that has been reserved for you dynamically. That means if you have a statement like this:

```
int *my_int_pointer;
my_int_pointer = malloc(sizeof(int));
```

than you need to free the memory that was allocated (reserved) by malloc.
if you are unsure where to free it than just free it at the end of the program, by using free;

```
free(my_int_pointer);
```

In your file it looks like there will be memory allocated whenever there is a new line in the file you read (in the `while(done==0)` loop). so everytime after the `if` in the this loop you have to free the memory that was used by the variable.

Furthermore you need to free the memory that was allocated by for the readline variable. But as it was pointed out before you may have a memory leak there.

Hope this helps.

edit: Okay - I was already wondering about the `csestrcpy` function. Lets have a look at this function:

```
char* csestrcpy2(char* src){
    int i = 0;
    char *dest;
    char t;
    dest = (char*) malloc(MAX_LINE); /*<<- This allocates memory that has to be freed*/
    while( src[i] != '\0'){
        dest[i] = src[i];
        i++;
    }
    dest[i] = '\0';
    //printf("length:%i\n",i);
    free(dest);                  /* This frees the memory, but you return a pointer */
    return dest;                 /* to this memory. this is invalid.                */
}
```

What you could however free is the src pointer in that function. but remember: the pointer cannot hold information after the underlying memory is freed! It just points to a place in memory where it should not write or read anymore.

Furthermore the function copys the string as long as there is no '\0'. What happens if there is no terminator? The function keeps on copying from some memory adresses where it should not!

you should not use that function ;)

Comment: tried to free to free the memory where you said and got the:  free(): invalid pointer: 0xb76f5000 maybe this is unfixable

Comment: Also you are correct about the read in... I have to read a file then store each line read in in as a properly sized null terminated string in an array of strings... this actually works just fine... Can I free the memory allocated for that array if i want to read the array later? If i do free it can i still read the array? How much memory can I malloc() before my program gets dead?

Comment: That is not the syntax for `free`.

Comment: whoops... i was just recently working with c++ and confused free(ptr); with delete ptr;

Comment: What will happen if I call call free() on a variable not created with malloc(), for instance, if I receive a pointer to a struct and I call free() on that, will my program crash or is it correct?

Answer (score 9):

There needs to be a call to `free()` for each successful call to `malloc()`.

That doesn't *necessarily* mean that you need to have equal numbers of `malloc()` and `free()` calls in your code; it means that for every `malloc()` call that's executed when your program runs, you should call `free()`, passing it the pointer value you got from `malloc()`.  `malloc()` allocates memory; `free()` tells the system that you're done with the allocated memory.

(You can almost certainly get away with not `free()ing` allocated memory when your program terminates, since it will be reclaimed by the operating system, but just as a matter of style and good practice you should still match `malloc()`s with `free()`s.)

I'm ignoring `calloc()` and `realloc()` calls.

Comment: Could you please describe scenario(s) where use of free() is an absolute must? Since OS handles it, why will someone ever get to use it (apart from having "good programming practice")?

Comment: @VikasGoel: Consider a program that loops indefinitely, allocating memory on each iteration. If it doesn't free its allocated memory, it will quickly run out.

Answer (score 3):

Dynamic memory allocation (malloc) allocates a memory block of requested size, and returns a pointer to the start of this block.Since we have taken this block from memory so its a good practice to return this back to memory after completion of task.

Now as answer of your question , To be always on safe side you can call free function before making return.

```
main{
    int *i;
    ..
    ..
    i=(int *)malloc(sizeof(int));
    ...//so something with i
    ..
    free(i);
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Think of `malloc` and `free` as "begin" and "end". ANY time you call `malloc`, do what you need to and once you're done, always call `free`. Make sure to only free it once, double-free is a runtime error.

If you somehow lose the value returned by `malloc` (yes, this is what's happening with your code), then you have a memory leak (and the gates of hell open up, yada yada).

To re-iterate: free whatever malloc returns (except null).

Comment: How do I kill the memory leak? or at least find out where it was?

Comment: You cannot 'kill' a memory leak, it happens when your program terminates without freeing memory it allocated. Most Operating systems keep track of memory allocated and free on their own but there is no guarantee. You would have to restart your operating system to recover the memory. You compile your program with debugging support enabled (-g in gcc) and then use a debugger such as gdb or valgrind. valgrind even has a tool called memcheck which shows list of memories which were allocated (and where)

Comment: Awesome thanks I also found a way to do a code re-write that needs only one malloc()... I appreciate all your help!

Comment: @Nalin: sorry, but that is incorrect. The OS does indeed keep track of memory allocated for a particular program. However when the program exits, the OS can and does reclaim all of that memory. The last OS that did *not* do this, iirc was Windows 98 (which is why it needed rebooting so often).

Comment: Actually, it is perfectly legal to `free()` a NULL pointer (e.g. returned by malloc in your last sentence). The libc will just do nothing, as specified in the standard. However, some coding guidelines may complain about doing this, as it may show that the programmer has no clear idea of what is going on with the allocated blocks and that there is possible memory leaks elsewhere.

Comment: I thought that was just `delete`. Interesting.

Comment: @Chris: Thanks for the info. That is what i meant by Modern Operating systems. But most embedded systems don't guarantee this. That is why i mentioned it. Either way, it's bad programming practice to leave memory leaks in your program. :)

Answer (score 0):

As a general rule, for every `malloc` there should be a corresponding `free`.  You cannot however `free` something twice (as you have noticed by now).  I don't see any calls to `free` in your code, so it's impossible to say where your problem lies, but I noticed right away that you `malloc` some memory and assign it to `readline` inside of a loop, yet you don't call `free` on `readline` at the end of the loop, so you are leaking memory there.

Comment: if i fee it at the end of the loop then the program dies... if i free it after the loop then the program dies... if i free it at the end of the program the program dies.... it seems to go like this for any combination of frees at any point in the program...

Comment: @Koffee: It certainly does not.  I meant at the end of each *iteration*.  The number of iterations is unknown, so you should be cleaning up after yourself.  What if you are reading a huge file?  Don't design your code to only work under the most trivial of conditions, and you should get into the habit of writing correct code anyway.

Answer (score 0):

```
        i++;
        j++;
        /// free here
        free(readline);
    }
    count++;

}
printf("current word count: %i", word_count);

//free here as well
for(int k = 0; k < count_number_of_lines; k++)
{
    free(strings_array[count_number_of_lines]);
}

return 0;
}
```

This should work.

In general - any memory allocated dynamically - using calloc/malloc/realloc needs to be freed using free() before the pointer goes out of scope.

If you allocate memory using 'new' then you need to free it using 'delete'.

Comment: tried both and they both give me 
 double free or corruption (top): 0x088113c8

Comment: Have edited the post. i'm sorry, the free should be just after the iterators, before the } and not after.
also
strings_array[count_number_of_lines]=(char*)malloc(strlen(incoming_string+1));
should be 
strings_array[count_number_of_lines]=(char*)malloc(strlen(incoming_string)+1));
then try freeing it like shown above - it should work

Comment: You've written free(dest) and then you are returning it!
It doesn't return a string.
you don't need to free the memory there. if you remove that and then free it at the end it should work fine.

Answer (score 0):

This line:

```
strings_array[count_number_of_lines]=(char*)malloc(strlen(incoming_string+1));
```

is being overriden by the line next to it, so it can be removed.

You should also add `free(readline)` after `count++` in the last loop to free the memory created by malloc.

Comment: i cannot remove that line or the array of strings never fills up thus when i try to access the array of strings later even just to print it it it gives me an array with nothing in it?

Comment: also i tried to add that free and got:
double free or corruption (top): 0x088113c8 and the program broke...